# use pyautogui in a certain open program in windows

Tags: python, pyautogui

I would like to use image search in a certain open application, for example, I want it to search the image only in the windows "Calculator" application, how could I do that?

Today pyautogui searches the whole screen, is it possible to limit only one open application?

```
def main():
    try:
        while True:
           button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/calc7Key.png', region=(0,0,1920, 1080), confidence=.5)
           print(button7location)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone.')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can program PyAutoGui to look only at the region of your Windows Taskbar. Below an example:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=(0,0, 300, 400))
```

Pass a region argument (a 4-integer tuple of (left, top, width, height))

See more in the  [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#:%7E:text=These%20%E2%80%9Clocate%E2%80%9D%20functions%20are%20fairly%20expensive%3B%20they%20can%20take%20a%20full%20second%20to%20run.%20The%20best%20way%20to%20speed%20them%20up%20is%20to%20pass%20a%20region%20argument%20(a%204%2Dinteger%20tuple%20of%20(left%2C%20top%2C%20width%2C%20height))%20to%20only%20search%20a%20smaller%20region%20of%20the%20screen%20instead%20of%20the%20full%20screen%3A)